# How to use "no matter what"

Tags: phrase-usage

> Travel let's us experience different cultures. **No matter what** dietary
>   habits or architecture, they are both different from country to
>   country.

**No matter what** using in this sentence is correct or not?
If it is wrong, how to modify it. Using **whether** or **regardless of**? I don't know

Answer (score 2):

You would not use the phrase "no matter what" in that case. It does not mean "whether" - it means "always".

You could say

> I will love you **no matter what**.

Which means "I will always love you, even if the situation changes".

The original sentence is wrong, or at least sounds strange.

If you want to say "many things are different in different cultures", you could say

> Travel lets us experience different cultures. Whether dietary habits or architecture, they are different from country to country.

But here, "They" would mean "different cultures". I think you're using it to mean "dietary habits or architecture", which is wrong in English.

Finally, you'd actually use "lets", not "let's". "Let's" would be short for "let is", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: So if I edit to the sentence "Whether dietary habits or architecture, they are different from country to country.", it will be correct?

Comment: Yes, it will be a correct sentence, as I said. But I'm not sure it will mean what you want to say. What are you trying to say with the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your phrase is not well structured. Let's forget the no matter what for a bit.

You are establishing a **disjunction**

> dietary habits OR architecture

followed by a **conjunction**

> they are both different from country to country
>  = 
> dietary habits AND architecture are both different from country to country

That's

> No matter what, dietary habits or architecture, dietary habits and architecture are both different from country to country

It doesn't sound well, is it? What about using just the conjuction?

> Usually dietary habits and architecture are different from country to country.

I've removed **no matter what** on purpose. According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-matter-what-when-why-etc), no matter what *is used to emphasize that something is always true*. I think that you can not assure that dietary habits or architecture are ALWAYS so different in close countries.